# Login users to website and google apps at the same time

Tags: php, web, single-sign-on

What I need to achieve is as follows: I have a website that access through mycompany.org. I also have a google apps account that I access through google.com/a/mycompany.org. What I need is for the users to log in to the website using their google apps identity and password (i.e. username@mycompany.org). After that, they need to access their google apps account simply by clicking a link, without having to login again.

So basically they need to login to the website and google apps at the same time.
Is this possible with some google apps API ?

I'm using PHP.